# Prologue in x86 Assembly and Pushing Callee Save Registers

Tags: c, assembly, x86, compiler-optimization, cpu-registers

While studying dis-assembly of C code this struck me. Generally, in the assembly of functions after saving frame pointer we push callee saved registers and revive them back just before return. x86 ABI tells us which registers are callee/caller save. However my problem starts when I see that compiler behaves differently in assembling those functions. For example:

```
Case 1
    (gdb) disassemble EVP_CipherInit_ex
    Dump of assembler code for function EVP_CipherInit_ex:
       0xb1258044 <+0>:     push   %ebp
       0xb1258045 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
       0xb1258047 <+3>:     push   %edi
       0xb1258048 <+4>:     push   %esi
       0xb1258049 <+5>:     push   %ebx

Case 2
    (gdb) disassemble FIPS_mode
    Dump of assembler code for function FIPS_mode:
       0xb12614c4 <+0>:     push   %ebp
       0xb12614c5 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
       0xb12614c7 <+3>:     push   %ebx
       0xb12614c8 <+4>:     sub    $0x4,%esp

Case 3
    (gdb) disassemble OPENSSL_init
    Dump of assembler code for function OPENSSL_init:
       0xb124fae4 <+0>:     push   %ebp
       0xb124fae5 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
       0xb124fae7 <+3>:     push   %ebx
       0xb124fae8 <+4>:     sub    $0x4,%esp

Case 4
    (gdb) disassemble FIPS_module_mode
    Dump of assembler code for function FIPS_module_mode:
       0xb117dfdc <+0>:     push   %edi
       0xb117dfdd <+1>:     push   %esi
       0xb117dfde <+2>:     push   %ebx
       0xb117dfdf <+3>:     sub    $0x10,%esp
```

Q1. In first three cases we saved frame pointer **ebp**, and another common register **ebx** but rest of the things vary. How does compiler identifies which ones to push and which ones to avoid? Is this some kind of optimization playing its game? Any pointers on this will be very helpful.

Q2. In the dis-assembly of **FIPS_module_mode** we have not even saved frame pointer **ebp**. I know that we can save space by optimizing that with a compiler option. My interest is in understanding whether this absence of frame pointer part is due to that explicit compiler optimization or are there certain other parameters that help in deciding this.

Q3. How does a debugger like gdb detects that for a specific function the in case 4, a frame pointer is omitted in the core-dump?

The prototypes of the functions posted are:

```
int FIPS_module_mode(void); 
void OPENSSL_init(void); 
int EVP_CipherInit_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,
                      ENGINE *impl, const unsigned char *key,
                      const unsigned char *iv, int enc);
int FIPS_mode(void);
```

This is running on NetBSD5 and coredump analyzed by gdb

Comment: Could we see the C? In particular, static functions are likely to ignore the ABI when optimisations are enabled.

Comment: Probably also need to know the platform - gdb implies linux, but may be mingw and windows and linux calling conventions differ

Comment: @Jon Chesterfield - None of the functions in question are static

Comment: Better ask the compiler to show its assembler code, e.g. with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -S` then look into the emitted `*.s` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**. gcc (like other optimizing compilers) compiles the whole function, using as many callee-saved registers as is useful, but only as many as needed.  The asm isn't generated until gcc is finished optimizing the whole function (or compilation-unit, or program), so gcc knows how many registers it will need when it's emitting the prologue.

Any callee-saved register it uses is pushed in the prologue and popped in the epilogue.  In some functions, it uses callee-saved register just because it runs out of caller-saved registers it can use without saving (so, just for number of total number of registers).  In non-leaf functions, callee-saved registers are also useful for keeping something in a register across a `call`, which gcc must assume clobbers all the caller-saved registers.

It looks like if gcc only needs one call-preserved register, it chooses `ebx`.  It might use (save/restore) just `esi/edi` if it wanted to use a `rep movs`  or something, though.

gcc's behaviour is sub-optimal sometimes: some functions have a fast-path that doesn't use many locals, but gcc emits code that pushes before checking, and thus has to pop again.  The Linux kernel hints some functions as `noinline` to keep the fast-path as fast as possible, at the expense of an extra function call in the slow path.  As I understand it, this is the main reason for noinline in Linux, rather than code-size bloat.

**Q2**. Yes, it looks like `FIPS_module_mode` was compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer` (which is the default in newer gcc).  If you're looking at a library, the Makefile (or whatever build system) could easily have built different files with different options.  Or, even with `-fomit-frame-pointer`, functions with variable-size local variables do build a stack frame.  e.g.
`int func(int c) { int tmp[c]; ...; }`

**Q3**. I got curious about how modern debuggers do stack backtraces without frame pointers.  [This blog post sheds some light](http://yosefk.com/blog/getting-the-call-stack-without-a-frame-pointer.html): there is debug info in the `.eh_frame_hdr` data section (not marked as "debug" info, so it doesn't normally get stripped, so you can backtrace when the call stack went through a function in a stripped library or something).  Use `objdump -h` to see the size of that section.  That data is also used for unwinding the stack if/when a runtime exception is thrown, so that's another reason for not stripping it.

In normal situations (barring bugs that clobber the stack, or compiler / asm-programming errors that mess up the stack pointer), it works without frame pointers, so `-fomit-frame-pointer` is the default in gcc since 4.6, even for x86.  I think it was the default for longer for x86-64.

Without that info, you could scan the stack for values that are in the right range to be return addresses.

Comment: Looks like I need to study few things before I understand your answer, however I didn't get the first line of 1st answer. "gcc uses as many callee-saved registers as is useful, but only when needed....". I think this is exactly my question. How gcc would know which callee save registers to be discarded and which ones to preserve? Since, a non-leaf function can be called by many other functions. +1 for your effort. Thanks.

Comment: It preserves all as per the calling convention. But if the function itself doesn't use one, it doesn't have to be pushed since it won't change.

Comment: @RIPUNJAY: When I say "uses", I mean it compiles the whole function, using as many registers as is helpful to hold all the values that need to be live at once to make fast code without spilling locals to memory.  If that takes more registers than are available in the set of caller-saved registers (i.e. can be used without saving), then it saves/restores some across the whole function.  Also, non-leaf means it *calls* other functions.  All functions can have multiple callers.  The main optimization for single-caller functions is to inline them.

Comment: @PeterCordes One of the ways gdb can distinguish the omit frame pointer case, in lieu of debug info, [not saying it _does_] is to look at the first few instructions.  If they're _push %ebp_ followed by _mov %esp,%ebp_ that indicates frame pointer.  Whenever I've disassembled, it's either been case 1-3 or case 4 and or sometimes func is so trivial that it can skip the _sub $0x10,%esp_.  All the differences show up early, so you can usually figure it out.  Similar problem if you want to write your own stack trace using  __builtin_return_address / __builtin_frame_address

Comment: @RIPUNJAYTRIPATHI: updated my answer with similar clarifications to what I wrote in comments.  I think it fully answers the question(s) now.

Comment: @Peter Cordes : Thanks for your posts and this answer, though I am convinced with your answer, keeping it "Unanswered" for a while so as to attract few more experts and their comments. Giving +1 to each your comment.

Comment: @RIPUNJAYTRIPATHI: ok, no worries.  didn't mean to rush you.  The only really unanswered question IMO is why one of the prologues omits the frame pointer, and the question doesn't provide enough info to answer that.  (My guess is that the build script builds that file without frame pointers.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes : Not really. Q1 and Q3 were more of interest. Q1 was relatively more intuitive in fact, I just did not strain my brain enough. In Q2 I also guessed the same about omission of frame pointer, and you gave good pointers in form of that link and I never knew nothing about that rep movs thing. So you helped me a lot.